# SASS and Liferay - how to use in custom themes?

Tags: sass, themes, liferay, liferay-theme

I don't really find an answer on liferay's blogs and google - so i hope anyone here can help me.

I'm trying to get started with sass in a custom theme i am building in liferay 6.2.

As i understand it, the approach would be this:

1. create an empty theme, (using maven,) based off _styled
2. this gives me a file layout like this:

   ```
   <theme>
     +-src
        +-main
           +-webapp
              +-css
                 +- ... here i'll put any css overwrites
   ```
3. develop sass stylesheets, link to `main.css`

   ```
   <theme>
     +-src
        +-main
           +-webapp
              +-css
                 +-main.css
                 +-custom.scss
   ```

*main.css* initially looks like this:

```
@import url(custom.css);

/* other css import here */
```

*custom.scss* would contain some SASS content:

```
$color: #f00;
body {
    color: $color;
}
```

Now my question: How do I link both CSS and SASS together correctly? How does the `@import` statement in *main.css* have to be defined?

I tried `@import url(custom.scss);` but this won't give me the desired results. Likewise, `@import url(custom.css);` won't do it either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution. Key is to understand that Liferay does not use the file extension `*.scss` on a theme's stylesheets. Just dropping my SASS code into a `*.css` file did the job!

Found the solution [here](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/26417942).

My directory layout:

```
<theme>
  +-src
     +-main
        +-webapp
           +-css
              +-main.css
              +-custom.css
```

*main.css* looks like:

```
@import url(custom.css);

/* other css import here */
```

and *custom.css* like this:

```
$color: #f00;
body {
    color: $color;
}
```

And the result is (in *custom.css*, after reloading on the web browser):

```
body {
    color: #f00;
}
```

Hooray!

Comment: so just to be clear, I can write sass directly into `custom.css` and liferay will convert that to css when it builds (i'm using maven)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are working in Liferay 6.2 file extension should be .css, but if you are working in Liferay 7/DXP it should be .scss.