# Liferay 6.2: Possibility to import Sass files from my theme into a portlets main.css

Tags: sass, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme

I’m diggin into Liferay theming with Sass.

One thing I really like to know is: How to make use of variables defined in the theme within a custom portlet.

Because I want to have generic theme related styles within my theme and portlet specific styles within the portlet to increase maintainabilty und portability.

Lets say I have the follwing file within my theme:
`css/_ aui_variables.scss`

Within this file I have overridden the default values of the Bootstrap variables defined in the parent theme:
`_styled/css/_aui_variables.scss`

Of course I would like to make use of these variables in my portlet specific Sass files which I would like to place within portlets `main.css` (which is compiled by the Sass parser as well).

**Please let me know that this is possible.**

When trying to import my variables in the portlets `main.css` via:

```
@import "foobar-default-theme/css/_aui_variables";
```

My console in Eclipse (Liferay IDE) shows me the following error message:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: foobar-default-theme/css/_aui_variables.
Load paths:
  /Users/mkuehnel/Documents/Projects/foobar/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/html/css/common
  /Users/mkuehnel/Documents/Projects/foobar/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/25-foobar-top-navigation-portlet/css
  /Users/mkuehnel/Documents/Projects/foobar/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/sass
  /Users/mkuehnel/Documents/Projects/foobar/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/liferay/ruby/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Users/mkuehnel/Documents/Projects/foobar/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/temp/liferay/ruby/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
/css/main.css:2
[…]
```

Any hints appreciated.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: I would be very interested in a solution to this - I have been unable to achieve this myself and have tried as many things as I can think of.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21835461/473016)

Comment: Thanks @anpsmn 

But this won’t help me, cause in that case they are talking about imports within the theme which works like a charm.

In my case I like to import a Sass file from my theme into a portlet of mine :[